# Injectivity of $\mathbb{Q}_{p}$ and $\mathbb{Z}(p^{\infty})$

Tags: p-adic-number-theory, injective-module

Please help me. In the category of $R$-modules, we know that the Prüfer group $\mathbb{Z}(p^{\infty})$ is an injective envelope of $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$ the ring integers modulo $p$ where $p$ is a prime number. But, I found that $\mathbb{Q}_{p}/\mathbb{Z}_{p}\cong \mathbb{Z}(p^{\infty})$, where $\mathbb{Z}_{p}$ is a $p$-adic integers and $\mathbb{Q}_{p}$ is a $p$-adic field. So, we we can construct an exact sequence:
$0\rightarrow \mathbb{Z}_{p}\rightarrow \mathbb{Q}_{p}\rightarrow\mathbb{Z}(p^{\infty})\rightarrow 0$ and we also have monomorphism from $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}\hookrightarrow \mathbb{Z}_{p}$. The $p$-adic field $\mathbb{Q}_{p}$ is an injective module as a $\mathbb{Z}$-modules, so there is a minimal injective module than $\mathbb{Z}(p^{\infty})$ containing $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$, which is $\mathbb{Q}_{p}$. But, the injective envelope of $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$ is $\mathbb{Z}(p^{\infty})$. I don't know where my mistake lies. Thank you so much for considering my questions.

Comment: You should specify which ring $R$ you're talking about.

Comment: What "monomorphism $\mathbb Z/p \mathbb Z \hookrightarrow \mathbb Z_p$" do we have?

Comment: $\sum_{i<1} a^{i} p^{i} \mod p \mapsto (a_{i})$ where $a_{i}=0$ for $i\neq 0$

Comment: I don't understand that, but whatever it is, I am quite sure it is not a ring homomorphism. Because there is no nonzero ring homomorphism (actually, not even a homomorphism of underlying additive groups) from characteristic $p$ to characteristic $0$.

Comment: I know my mistake now, $(a_{i})$ with $a_{i}=0$ except $i=0$ is not in $p$-adic integers because $(a_{i})\notin \mathbb{Z}$. Thank you for considering my question.

Answer (score 1):

In fact, $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$ does not embed in $\mathbb{Q}_p$ at all. $\mathbb{Q}_p$ is torsion-free, but $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$ is torsion, so the only homomorphism $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Q}_p$ is the zero map.

$\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$ *does* embed in $\mathbb{Z}(p^\infty)$ however, so it makes sense to claim that $\mathbb{Z}(p^\infty)$ is the injective envelope of $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$ (and this is true!)

Comment: Thank you for considering my question.